# For what duration is sudo_root in "don't-prompt-for-password" mode?

Tags: command-line, sudo

The first time a user enters `sudo foo`, **sudo_root** prompts for the password. For a certain duration after that, **sudo_root** doesn't prompt for a password for any subsequent `sudo foo`'s in that terminal session.

- What duration is that?
- Can the duration be changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered in the Ubuntu Sudo FAQ entry here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Sudo

The default is 15 minutes, but can be changed with *timestamp_timeout* in `/etc/sudoers`. For more details see ["man sudoers"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudoers)

Comment: Here's a cheatsheet from http://www.webupd8.org/2010/04/how-to-change-sudo-password-time-out-in.html       
type `sudo visudo`      
go the line that says `Defaults env_reset`        
and change it to     
`Defaults env_reset , timestamp_timeout=X` 
with X in minutes

Comment: FYI: `sudo -k` invalidates an active sudo session. That is useful if you've huge `timestamp_timeout` values and do not plan to do any `sudo` stuff in the next minutes.