# Is there a way to never have to put in your password after you have logged in?

Tags: 11.04, sudo, password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Ubuntu remember forever the password after the first time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43969/how-to-make-ubuntu-remember-forever-the-password-after-the-first-time)

I put my password in when I log in but after that I don't want to type it again.

When I use my laptop I only wants to put in my password when I log in and never when I'm logged in.

The point of this is that I don't want to waste time typing my password every time I do some administrative task. I'm the only user and is very tired of having to type my password over and over again.

Comment: But I want to put in my password when I log in (for security.) But I don't want to put in my password after that.

Comment: This might be a security issue if someone else get access to your computer.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48243/why-cant-non-admin-users-install-software/48249#48249 and
http://askubuntu.com/questions/43969/how-to-make-ubuntu-remember-forever-the-password-after-the-first-time/43978#43978

Comment: @N.N that wont happen since I always lock my screen before I leave my computer and I always require a password when I log in!

Comment: @Alvar What about network access?

Comment: of course someone will have to put in a passwd to log in throw the network! My idea is that you only need a passwd to log in to the computer, since you are already logged in why do you need to verify that you hare root?

Answer (score 2):

Being able to run command with administrative privileges without entering a password is like doing everything as root. It's strongly discouraged to disable the password for sudo, although it's possible.

To skip asking for a password when installing programs, see:

- [How to prevent system applications (like the Software Center) from asking for password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18222/6969)

If you want to be able to use `sudo` without asking for a password (not recommended), follow the instructions at:

- [Always Sudo Privileges](https://askubuntu.com/q/20984/6969)

Comment: I want to use my passwd to log in, but after that I dont want to type it again, I lock my screen when I leave it, and if someone trys to access it from the internet then they MUST type in the passwd, if that is the case, why is this a security problem?

Comment: You're missing one serious issue: the possibility that code may be executed due to a bug or uncareful handling of code from the Internet. Consider changing the expiration time for a sudo session instead: http://askubuntu.com/q/18688/6969